# Issue in installing Android platform 2.2

Tags: cross-platform, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am new to titanium, i already set Android sdk its working fine with my eclipse indigo. I mean i can able to launch android 2.2 google api emulator in that IDE. But In titanium it showing error message **Items required An Android SDK is missing.Titanium requires Android platform 2.2** I have follow this post [Titanium Studio cannot find Android SDK](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/132614/titanium-studio-cannot-find-android-sdk-tried-multiple-solutions) and fixed some path issues. But still i am getting same error. Need guidance to set up environment.[image: Check this]

Comment: Do you have the Android 2.2 (API 8) installed?  This would be in your Android SDK Manager.

Comment: @Martin yeah i have.. u want me to take screen shoot ??? i have sdk and google api for 2.2

Comment: Do you have Android path set in Preferences > Studio > Platforms > Android?

Comment: Yeah i did... now i plan to reinstall titanium again because its not updating ACS showing error in that..